# How can I show multiple plots within one panel in R?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have the following plots and I want to show all of them within one panel! How can I do it using a matrix? Also I would like to know if there are other methods rather than using `matrix` and `layout`.

```
> plot(density(Boston$tax))
> rug(Boston$tax, col=2, lwd=3.5)
> hist(Boston$tax)
> rug(Boston$tax, col=2, lwd=3.5)
> table(Boston$chas)
Off  On 
471  35 
> barplot(table(Boston$chas))

> f1<-layout(matrix(c(0, 1,1,1,0,2,2,2,0,3,3,3) ,nrow = 4, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE))
> layout.show(f1)
```

I want to have a structure like this for my plot 1, 2 and 3:

```
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    0    1    1   1
## [2,]    0    2    2   2
## [3,]    0    3    3   3
## [4,]    blank0    0   0
```

However the output of my code shows something different:
[image]
Can someone explain to me how is the following figure c(...) has been constructed?
[image]

Comment: I know there's something like this : `layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4), nrow = 4, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE))` I am not sure how to put my three plots in the up right 3*3 corner!!! Like I am not sure about `c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4)`. Any hint?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how the matrix controls layouts. Try making up different matrices, setting them as layouts then looking at `layout.show` to see how the plotting device is divided up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `?layout`

```
Description:

     ‘layout’ divides the device up into as many rows and columns as
     there are in matrix ‘mat’, with the column-widths and the
     row-heights specified in the respective arguments.
```

So if our matrix is

```
matrix(1:4, 2, 2, byrow = TRUE)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    2
## [2,]    3    4
```

our lay out is like so

[image]

if we only want 1 plot on the top row we can specify our matrix as

```
matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    1
## [2,]    2    3
```

and the layout will be

[image]

```
mat <- matrix(1:3, 3, 3)
mat <- rbind(cbind(0, mat), 0)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    0    1    1    1
## [2,]    0    2    2    2
## [3,]    0    3    3    3
## [4,]    0    0    0    0
```

[image]

```
layout(mat)

plot(density(Boston$tax))
rug(Boston$tax, col=2, lwd=3.5)
hist(Boston$tax)
rug(Boston$tax, col=2, lwd=3.5)
barplot(table(Boston$chas))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please take a look at the updated question? Thanks for the great explanation.